# Ayuda con polygons y geoIntersects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una tabla con coordenadas que descargue de un api y me comentaron que con un poligono virtual podria sacar si paso o no por ahi el dispositivo ... pero es algo muy nuevo para mi

Las coordenadas las obtengo del mismo GPS pero no me regresa nada al momento de la consulta

```
db.getCollection('geozonas').find({polygons: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -106.404068,
                      31.5756798
                ]
            }
        }
        }})
```

y los puntos donde quiero saber son estos

```
db.getCollection('geozonas').find({GeoName: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}, {points: 1, _id: 0})

{
    "points" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "x" : -106.409294128418,
                "y" : 31.5745468139648
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.405494689941,
                "y" : 31.5714015960693
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.401100158691,
                "y" : 31.5754776000977
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.40470123291,
                "y" : 31.5785121917725
            }, 
            {
                "x" : -106.409294128418,
                "y" : 31.5745468139648
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tl;dr***

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una [consulta geoespacial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/index.html) a una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com) de tal forma que devuelva los resultados de la intersección de ciertas coordenadas con un polígono establecido.

**SOLUCIÓN**

En tu pregunta no queda claro si la consulta la harás contra documentos almacenados en la Base de Datos o si tomarás un valor devuelto por un dispositivo GPS y tratarás de determinar si el mismo está dentro de un área preestablecida en tu base de datos. Es por ello que me enfocaré en ambos escenarios.

**Resumen**

Para saber si un dispositivo GPS (que define una localización mediante un par de coordenadas numéricas tipo `[longitud, latitud]`), ha estado dentro de una zona geográfica definida, podemos usar tanto el operador de consulta geoespacial [`$geoIntersects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) o el operador [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/), de MongoDB.

La consulta en cuestión se realiza sobre la colección que almacena las coordenadas del dispositivo en un campo que almacena un objeto [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/) de tipo [Point](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#point).

Por ejemplo, dada la colección `locations`, una consulta en Mongo que muestre todos los documentos cuyo par de coordenadas se encuentran dentro de una geozona, sería la siguiente:

```js
let searchArea = { // objeto GeoJSON
  type: 'polygon',
  coordinates: [
    [
      [
        -106.409294128418,  // coordenada inicial
        31.5745468139648
      ],
      [
        -106.405494689941,
        31.5714015960693
      ],
      [
        -106.401100158691,
        31.5754776000977
      ],
      [
        -106.40470123291,
        31.5785121917725
      ],
      [
        -106.409294128418,  // coordenada final debe coincidir con inicial
        31.5745468139648
      ]
    ]
  ]
};
db.getCollection('locations').find(
  {
    loc: {
      $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: searchArea
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Esto nos devolverá la lista de documentos de la colección `locations` cuyo campo `loc` contiene una coordenada que se ubica dentro del área de búsqueda.

Puedes ver un ejemplo de esta implementación en el siguiente [enlace](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Prqvji_Ep6H) de [*Mongo Playground*](https://mongoplayground.net/).

**Respuesta larga**

Vamos a partir por definir los 2 posibles escenarios que no quedan claros en tu pregunta:

- Almaceno los datos devueltos por un dispositivo GPS en una colección de la base de datos, para ser consultados con posterioridad.
- Obtengo (o leo) un par de coordenadas en vivo desde el dispositivo GPS y deseo saber si las mismas están contenidas dentro de una región, sin almacenar los datos en la base de datos.

Si tu caso es la primera opción (lo cual tiene más sentido), entonces usar una consulta geoespacial sería la solución al problema.

En cambio, si el caso es el segundo, no sería necesaria una consulta geoespacial, por el contrario, el problema se resuelve usando simples (pero no triviales) matemáticas.

**Almacenando los datos del GPS en la base de datos**

Partiendo del supuesto que se almacenan los datos de localización del dispositivo GPS en la base de datos, vamos a ver una forma de realizar la consulta.

Nuestra colección para almacenar los datos puede contener documentos con al menos 3 valores para poder identificar el dispositivo, la fecha y hora de la captura de datos y las coordenadas del mismo en ese instante.

Por ejemplo:

```js
{
  device: <String>, // (o <ObjectId> apuntando a otra colección como referencia)
  location: <Point> // (objeto GeoJSON de tipo Point)
  date: <Date>      // tipo Date que que indica fecha y hora UTC de la captura de datos
}
```

Supongamos que leemos los datos de un dispositivo GPS y deseamos almacenarlos en un documento de la base de datos usando Mongoose, un ejemplo de esquema y de cómo construir el modelo sería parecido al siguiente:

```js
// esquema de Mongoose
const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  device: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}, {collection: 'locations'});

// nuestro modelo
const Location = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);

// leemos las coordenadas del GPS con
// alguna función que devuelve datos de la forma [longitud, latitud]
let gpsCoords = getGPSCoordinates(gpsId);

let location = new Location({
  device: gpsId,
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: gpsCoords
  },
  date: Date.now()
});

// salvamos en la BD
location.save(callback);
```

Una vez que tenemos los datos almacenados de esta forma en la base de datos, podemos usar una consulta para determinar si algún dispositivo estuvo dentro de la zona delimitada (que obtenemos de un documento, según lo que muestras en tu pregunta). Entonces vamos a convertir los datos devueltos de la colección `geozona` (así se llama la colección de donde obtienes el polígono en tu pregunta) en un objeto GeoJSON de tipo [*Polygon*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon).

```js
// hacemos la consulta a la DB para obtener lo siguiente:
// let points = db.getCollection('geozonas').find({GeoName: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}, {points: 1, _id: 0})[0].points;

// imitando el resultado tenemos:
let points = [ 
  [ 
    {
      "x" : -106.409294128418,
      "y" : 31.5745468139648
    }, 
    {
      "x" : -106.405494689941,
      "y" : 31.5714015960693
    }, 
    {
      "x" : -106.401100158691,
      "y" : 31.5754776000977
    }, 
    {
      "x" : -106.40470123291,
      "y" : 31.5785121917725
    }, 
    {
      "x" : -106.409294128418,
      "y" : 31.5745468139648
    }
  ]
];

// convertimos en coordenadas válidas para un tipo Polygon

let coordinates = [points[0].map(point => { return [point.x, point.y]})];

// declaramos nuestro polígono

let searchArea = {
  type: 'Polygon', // tipo de objeto GeoJSON
  coordinates
}

console.log(searchArea);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos lo necesario para realizar la consulta geoespacial sobre la colección de documentos de localización de dispositivos GPS, por ejemplo:

```js
// ...
// obtenemos el polígono y lo almacenamos en la variable searchArea
// ...
let insideArea = db.getCollection('locations').find({
  location: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $geometry: searchArea
    }
  }
});

// insideArea será una lista con todos los documentos que contengan un punto dentro del área de búsqueda.
```

Si la lista produce resultados es que al menos 1 dispositivo estuvo dentro del área de búsqueda en algún momento. Si en cambio, la lista está vacía, significa que ningún dispositivo ha entrado dentro de la zona de búsqueda.

**Búsqueda en vivo, sin almacenar en la base de datos**

Para este caso, obtenemos o leemos los datos de localización del GPS en un momento dado y queremos verificar si el dispositivo se encuentra dentro de un área establecida.

Si bien puede ser más fácil almacenar esa información en la base de datos, y luego realizar una consulta geoespacial sobre ese conjunto de datos recién almacenado, es posible hacerlo sin tener que almacenar la data.

Usaremos una técnica geométrica que permite determinar si un punto se encuentra dentro del perímetro de un polígono. Para ello tomamos el punto de muestra y extendemos una linea recta desde el mismo hacia la derecha hasta infinito. Si la linea recta se interseca con las aristas del polígono, un número par de veces ([0 es considerado par](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paridad_del_cero)), significa que el punto se encuentra fuera del polígono, en cambio si el número de intersecciones es impar, entonces el punto está dentro del polígono. Lo podemos apreciar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Ejemplo de puntos dentro y fuera de un área definida por un polígono]

En la imagen se aprecia que los puntos rojos están fuera del área definida por el polígono irregular delimitado de color negro, cada linea azul de dichos puntos rojos corta o interseca con las aristas del polígono un número par de veces. En cambio, los puntos verdes (incluido el que se encuentra sobre una arista) tienen rectas azules que interseca al polígono un número impar de veces.

Con esta técnica no importa la forma del polígono, simplemente con contar el número de intersecciones de la recta extendida a la derecha, sabremos si el punto está dentro o fuera del mismo.

¿Cómo lo hacemos?

Aquí se necesita cierto conocimiento de matemáticas y en especial de geometría en el plano, sin embargo si se presta atención a lo que se va a hacer puede ser fácil entenderlo.

Lo primero: definir el punto y el área de búsqueda. El punto nos lo da el dispositivo GPS en un par numérico de la forma `[longitud, latitud]`, y el área de búsqueda (el polígono) lo obtenemos de una consulta a la base de datos.

Definimos una [Clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes) llamada Point, que almacena dos valores `x` e `y`, que representarán la longitud y la latitud respectivamente:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Usaremos una función para determinar la [co-linealidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colinealidad) de 3 puntos `p`, `q`, `r`. Esta función devolverá un valor negativo si al ir de `p` a `q` y luego a `r` se produce una rotación en sentido contrario a las agujas del reloj. Si el valor devuelto es positivo, significa que se produce una rotación en el sentido de las agujas del reloj, y si devuelve cero (0), significa que los 3 puntos son co-lineales.

```js
const rotation = (p, q, r) => {
  let slopeDiff = ((q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x)) - ((q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y));
  return slopeDiff > 0 ? 1 : (slopeDiff === 0 ? 0 : -1);
}
```

También usaremos una función que nos permita determinar si un punto `p` se encuentra entre dos puntos `q` y `r`, siendo los 3 puntos co-lineales. En otras palabras, dados 3 puntos sobre la misma recta, determinar si `p` se encuentra en el segmento de recta definido por 'QR'.

```js
const onSegment = (p, q, r) => {
  return (
    p.x <= Math.max(q.x, r.x) &&
    p.x >= Math.min(q.x, r.x) &&
    p.y <= Math.max(q.y, r.y) &&
    p.y >= Math.min(q.y, r.y)
  );
}
```

Ahora, podemos definir una función que calcule si dos segmentos de recta se intersecan. Cada segmento de recta se compone de 2 pares de puntos.

```js
const intersect = (p, q, r, s) => {
  // segmentos definidos por PQ y RS

  // buscamos las 4 posibles rotaciones
  let rotation_1 = rotation(p, q, r);
  let rotation_2 = rotation(p, q, s);
  let rotation_3 = rotation(r, s, p);
  let rotation_4 = rotation(r, s, q);

  // Caso General: los segmentos de recta se intersecan en un punto
  if(rotation_1 !== rotation_2 && rotation_3 !== rotation_4) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: p, q, r son co-lineales
  // y 'r' se encuentra en el segmento PQ
  if(!rotation_1 && onSegment(r, p, q)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: p, q, s son co-lineales
  // y 's' se encuentra en el segmento PQ
  if(!rotation_2 && onSegment(s, p, q)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: r, s, p son co-lineales
  // y 'p' se encuentra en el segmento RS
  if(!rotation_3 && onSegment(p, r, s)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: r, s, q son co-lineales
  // y 'q' se encuentra en el segmento RS
  if(!rotation_4 && onSegment(q, r, s)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: los segmentos de recta PQ y RS son paralelos o son co-lineales
  return false;
}
```

Ahora ya podemos definir la función que determinará si un punto está dentro de un polígono o no. Primero definimos el polígono, el cual es simplemente una lista de `n` *Puntos* que definen una figura cerrada. Esto es, el primer vértice (Punto) está unido con el segundo, el segundo con el tercero, ..., el enésimo con el primero.

Llamaremos a esta lista de puntos `polygon`.

```js
const inside = (polygon, p) => {
  // Verificamos que el polígono tiene más de tres lados (no hay polígonos de menos de 3 lados)
  if(polygon.length < 3) return false;
  
  // ahora establecemos el valor del punto extremo para trazar la linea recta desde 'p'
  // en el sistema de posicionamiento global los valores de longitud están en el
  // rango [-180, 180] ambos inclusive, por lo tanto en ese rango, hacia la derecha
  // 181 representará infinito.
  const inf = new Point(181, p.y); // <- valor de 'y' igual a  'p.y' (recta horizontal)
  let numberOfIntersections = 0;
  for(let i = 1; i < polygon.length; ++i) {
    // verificamos si los segmentos se intersecan
    if(intersect(polygon[i - 1], polygon[i], p, inf)) {
      // verificamos la colinealidad de 'p' con respecto a los vértices del polígono
      // que estamos evaluando y si el punto se halla entre ambos vértices.
      if(!rotation(p, polygon[i - 1], polygon[i])){
        return onSegment(p, polygon[i - 1], polygon[i]);
      }
      numberOfIntersections++;
    }
  }
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de verificar en vivo si un dispositivo GPS se encuentra dentro de una geozona o se encuentra fuera de la misma. Uno de los requisitos para usar este sistema es que el área poligonal sea un área cerrada, y que tenga al menos 3 aristas (no existen polígonos de 2 o menos aristas). El valor inicial de la lista de vértices debe ser igual al valor final, para garantizar el cierre.

Como el área del polígono se obtiene de la base de datos, habrá que convertir cada valor en un punto como está definido en nuestra clase.

Un ejemplo funcional:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const rotation = (p, q, r) => {
  let slopeDiff = ((q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x)) - ((q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y));
  return slopeDiff > 0 ? 1 : (slopeDiff === 0 ? 0 : -1);
}

const onSegment = (p, q, r) => {
  return (
    p.x <= Math.max(q.x, r.x) &&
    p.x >= Math.min(q.x, r.x) &&
    p.y <= Math.max(q.y, r.y) &&
    p.y >= Math.min(q.y, r.y)
  );
}

const intersect = (p, q, r, s) => {
  // segmentos definidos por PQ y RS

  // buscamos las 4 posibles rotaciones
  let rotation_1 = rotation(p, q, r);
  let rotation_2 = rotation(p, q, s);
  let rotation_3 = rotation(r, s, p);
  let rotation_4 = rotation(r, s, q);

  // Caso General: los segmentos de recta se intersecan en un punto
  if(rotation_1 !== rotation_2 && rotation_3 !== rotation_4) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: p, q, r son co-lineales
  // y 'r' se encuentra en el segmento PQ
  if(!rotation_1 && onSegment(r, p, q)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: p, q, s son co-lineales
  // y 's' se encuentra en el segmento PQ
  if(!rotation_2 && onSegment(s, p, q)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: r, s, p son co-lineales
  // y 'p' se encuentra en el segmento RS
  if(!rotation_3 && onSegment(p, r, s)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: r, s, q son co-lineales
  // y 'q' se encuentra en el segmento RS
  if(!rotation_4 && onSegment(q, r, s)) {
    return true;
  }

  // Caso especial: los segmentos de recta PQ y RS son paralelos o son co-lineales
  return false;
}

const inside = (polygon, p) => {
  // Verificamos que el polígono tiene 4 vértices (el primero y el último deben repetirse)
  if(polygon.length < 4) return false;
  
  // ahora establecemos el valor del punto extremo para trazar la linea recta desde 'p'
  // en el sistema de posicionamiento global los valores de longitud están en el
  // rango [-180, 180] ambos inclusive, por lo tanto en ese rango, hacia la derecha
  // 181 representará infinito.
  const inf = new Point(181, p.y); // <- valor de 'y' igual a  'p.y' (recta horizontal)
  let numberOfIntersections = 0;
  for(let i = 1; i < polygon.length; ++i) {
    // verificamos si los segmentos se intersecan
    if(intersect(polygon[i - 1], polygon[i], p, inf)) {
      // verificamos la colinealidad de 'p' con respecto a los vértices del polígono
      // que estamos evaluando y si el punto se halla entre ambos vértices.
      if(!rotation(p, polygon[i - 1], polygon[i])){
        return onSegment(p, polygon[i - 1], polygon[i]);
      }
      numberOfIntersections++;
    }
  }
  return (numberOfIntersections % 2 === 0 ? false : true);
};

// puntos tal como se reciben de la BD
let points = [ 
  {
      "x" : -106.409294128418,
      "y" : 31.5745468139648
  }, 
  {
      "x" : -106.405494689941,
      "y" : 31.5714015960693
  }, 
  {
      "x" : -106.401100158691,
      "y" : 31.5754776000977
  }, 
  {
      "x" : -106.40470123291,
      "y" : 31.5785121917725
  }, 
  {
      "x" : -106.409294128418,
      "y" : 31.5745468139648
  }
];

let Polygon = points.map(point => {return new Point(point.x, point.y)});

let puntos = [
  new Point(-106.404068, 31.5756798), // <- punto de la pregunta original
  new Point(-106.504168, 31.6756798),
  new Point(-106.405051, 31.5776798), // <- punto dentro del polígono
  new Point(-106.304068, 31.4056798),
  new Point(-106.714068, 31.5956798)
];

puntos.forEach((punto, index) => {
  console.log(`¿El punto ${index +  1} está dentro del polígono? ${inside(Polygon, punto)}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Diferencia entre `$geoIntersects` y `$geoWithin`**

Cuando aplicamos cualquiera de estos operadores de consulta sobre objetos de tipo `Point` no existe una diferencia, pero cuando los aplicamos sobre objetos de tipo [`LineString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#linestring) o sobre objetos [`Polygon`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon) si que hay una diferencia. Podemos ver la siguiente imagen para entenderlo un poco mejor, el área de búsqueda es el cuadro de color verde y se aprecia lo que devuelve `$geoIntersects` y `$geoWithin` aplicado en cada caso sobre el área con forma de estrella:

[image: Diferencia entre $geoIntersects y $geoWithin]

El operador `$geoWithin` devolverá todos los documentos que representen objetos totalmente contenidos en el área de búsqueda.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Amigooo, realmente me explicaste todo!! te agradezco demaciado, me quedo muy en claro todo!! y solo decirte que esta funcionando ya !!! 

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Excelente, igual editaré para dar una mayor explicación de la parte matemática, porque no queda muy claro todo el proceso y el porqué lo hago así. Saludos